# onStop() Timing out

Tags: java, android

I have an application that has a while loop in the onStop() method. In the logs I found this line:

```
07-06 08:35:43.616 W/ActivityManager(  837): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{4271e7f0 u0 com.example.jalexander.copyright/.MainActivity t307}
07-06 08:35:43.616 V/ActivityManager(  837): Moving to STOPPED: ActivityRecord{4271e7f0 u0 com.example.jalexander.copyright/.MainActivity t307} (stop complete)
```

The application is not completing it's onStop() task, and I am wondering if this may be the cause. Additionally, are there any issues I should be aware of given that my application sort of lingers in onStop() while in the backstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your loop an `n` of `0` and see if it's still happening.  Those lifecycle methods are not intended to do any heavy lifting and the OS is getting grumpy about it.  It would be wise to put that loop into an `AsyncTask` or otherwise trying to find a way to do that work elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by n of 0? Also would it work to put the loop inside of an IntentService instead of an AsyncTask? Just to be sure it doesn't get shut down.

Comment: @Jon I mean make your loop do 0 iterations.  And yes, putting the loop in an `IntentService` is a fine idea.

Comment: I put the loop in an IntentService and it worked out well, thank you.